# Expressions<func>?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Can anyone explain what is the use of `expressions<func>`?

Comment: Can you be a little more precise? Is expressions a type or some placeholder? Because this looks like generics to me.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context?  This is going to be hard for anyone to answer otherwise.

Comment: You mean like numbers.Sum(w => w * w) ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean [`Expression<Func>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx)? There's no such class as `Expressions<Func>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you mean `Expression<Func>` where `Func` is any variety of the generic `Func` delegate.

If this is to be the case, what `Expression<Func>` is doing is getting an expression tree of the lambda that you're passing in its place.  You'll find this most commonly on the variants of `IQueryable<T>` or in many fluent interfaces.

The expression trees are used at run-time to generally translate the lambda expression into some other format.  Such as SQL in the case of LINQ to SQL.

You can read up more on [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)
And more about [expression trees in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where each node is an expression, for example, a method call or a binary operation such as x < y`

You can read more [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> Represents a strongly typed lambda expression as a data structure in the form of an expression tree

Here's a real world example of it's use that shows why it's useful: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

> A lambda expression is an anonymous
>   function that can contain expressions
>   and statements, and can be used to
>   create delegates or expression tree
>   types.